# AppFabricCaching Service DOWN in SharePoint 2016 On Prim

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, app-fabric, sharepoint-admin-center

Please find powershell script used below & do the needful.

[image]

James Please find image here. Am unable to add this image in comments.
[image]

Comment: You will need to provide a clearer breakdown of your problem, what you have tried to resolve it. Try not to just provide a single screenshot without clarification.

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Comment: Yes Waqas service is up and running as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following power shell script of which will delete the instance and recreate it.

```
$s = Get-SPServiceInstance <<Distributed Cache GUID>>

$s.delete()

Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

You will also need to confirm the Windows service for AppFabric is running.

If this still fails and you are not able to get the cache up. You may be required to install Cumulative Update 7 (KB3092423) for Microsoft AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server

https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/3092423

Comment: Thanks James, But some thing unusual is happening here. The moment I am clicking over below fix hyperlink its making service down again & I need to re perform entire activity again.